# Comparing an Argument with an Integer in C++

Tags: c++, parameters

I'm playing around with command line arguments and I've been trying to have a comparison between the argument number and the input. So if someone input 1 then the output would be "The difficulty level is 1".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(ijnt argc, char* argv[])
{
int a; 
if (argc[1] == '1')
    {
    cout << "The difficulty level is " << argv[1] << endl;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

I made the comparing 1 a char but I get the error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]" and says that the error is

```
if (argv[1] == '1')
```

How do I get the 1 that is getting compared to, to be accepted as a char?

Comment: Consider comparing `std::string(argv[1])` with `std::string("1")`.

Comment: When I do that, all the program comes back with is "1 is the number you entered" (or any number inputted) I want the program to output "The difficulty level is (the inputted number)" .

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is an array of character array...

So, use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) and compare, or better still, convert it to an `std::string` and compare... But also make sure that `argc` is greater than 1. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int a; 
if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "1") == 0)
    {
    cout << "The difficulty level is " << argv[1] << endl;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int a; 
if (argc > 1 && string(argv[1]) == "1")
    {
    cout << "The difficulty level is " << argv[1] << endl;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that but it didn't work so I changed argc to argv and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is `if (*argv[1] == '1')`

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments are character arrays and so you need to use something like `std::strcmp()` to compare them like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // check argument exists ...

    if(!std::strcmp(argv[1], "1")) // 0 when equal
    {
        // they are the same here
    }

    // ...
}
```

It may be simpler to just create a `std::string out of the arg

```
    if(std::string(argv[1]) == "1")
    {
        // they are the same here
    }
```

In all cases make sure you check whether or not the argument is present:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(!argv[1]) // argument not present (null terminated array)
    {
         std::cerr << "Expected an argument." << std::endl;
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // process arg here

    // ...
}
```